# How do I measure the size of an area?

Tags: software-recommendation, design

I'm looking for something to easily measure the height/width of items on screen in pixels.

Comment: Hi @Craig , if some of the answers provided solved your needs, could you please mark it as accepted?

Comment: See this answer to a similar question: http://askubuntu.com/a/583733/177068

Answer (score 62):

There are two packages in the repositories:

- [Screen ruler](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/screenruler.1.html)

  `sudo apt-get install screenruler`
- [kruler](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/kruler.1.html)

I haven't tried either of them, but they might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I installed screenruler after reading this comment. It works well.

Comment: Screenruler for Gnome (Ubuntu), and kruler for KDE (Kubuntu)

Comment: Whoah! +1 screenruler! this is awesome! This is a very necessary tool for desktop-customization and obsessive UI tweakers, like ms gamerchick. ;D

Comment: I will comment something I just found: Screenruler is good, but does not show a number of pixels by default, just a hardly-visible tiny hashmarks. you have to right click and set "track mouse" to do this.

Comment: Glad to help out. :)  I hope it helped the OP.

Comment: I installed screen ruler and for some reason it does not work. It is simply not visible, there is only the icon on the Unity launch bar. Does anyone know why? I have Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: screen ruler wont work with ubuntu 14

Comment: Both do not allow an arbitrary ruler angle.

Comment: Both links are dead now.

Comment: Sadly, none of these applications let us measure things that are not either horizontal or vertical...
I would love a tool that lets you click two points anywhere on the screen, and that tells you the distance between. Has anyone seen something like that ?

Comment: Screenruler is a fantastic and fully-functional program, even now.

Comment: The second link is DOA.

Answer (score 5):

Screen Ruler, which can be found in your Ubuntu Software Center is great.
But there is also another excellent tool that is available from installing Screenlets from the software center. Just type "ruler" in the search box after installing screenlets.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are going to use it for web design or web development then I would use the Web Developer extension within the FireFox Web browser. It also has tons of other useful tools which can be very helpful in your designs or development. It works great for CSS designs.

Take a look at it here https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/ .
I also think they have it for Chrome. This will provide you with a great on screen ruler for all your design projects.